# Testing strict equality with Jest for an object created with a class

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Say I have a class called DummyClass which creates an object like we always do with `new` keyword. I don't have issues with that but I'm trying to test if the object that is created with DummyClass equals an object based on an instance of DummyClass.

Let's say this is the class:

```
class DummyClass {
  /** @type {string} */
  name;

  /** @type {number} */
  age;

  /** @type {Date} */
  datetime;

  constructor(input) {
    this.name = input.name;
    this.age = input.age;
    this.datetime = input.datetime;
  }
}
```

In my Jest test, I'm trying to test it like this:

```
import DummyClass from '../dummy-class.js';

it('should have the same data', () => {
  const data = new DummyClass('John', 23, 'someDate');

  expect(data).toStrictEqual({
    name: 'John',
    age: 23,
    datetime: 'someDate'
  });
});
```

It doesn't pass of course as the object I provided in `toStrictEqual` is not an instance of DummyClass but a plain object.

How can I make it an instance of DummyClass? In my actual code the data in there is huge and I can't assert one by one.

Comment: In this case there's very little point `DummyClass` being a class, it _could_ just be a vanilla object.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It was just a small piece of a big project at work. I was just stuck at asserting the strict equal part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Here's the test:

```
it('should have the same data', () => {
  const data = new DummyClass('John', 23, 'someDate');

  expect(data).toStrictEqual(new DummyClass('John', 23, 'someDate'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your answer is that you are duplicating the same instantiation code in both sides of the test, so it won't fail never even if your code is wrong.

Instead, you can independently test object structure and class, like this:

```
it('should have the same data', () => {
  const data = new DummyClass('John', 23, 'someDate');

  expect(data).toEqual({
    name: 'John',
    age: 23,
    datetime: 'someDate'
  });
  expect(data).toBeInstanceOf(DummyClass)
});
```